# Command to find string and replace another string PROBLEM 2 (txt format)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to find a string in a txt format and each time it's found then look for an specific string to change for another string. Also, what follows that string is the length of the hexadecimal txt

Imagine the nexts hexadecimal txt:

Example 1:

```
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01   
b7 09 01 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   
17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83   
07 91 94 71 06 00 07 19
```

Example 2:

```
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 2b 03 4b 27 a1 25 02 01   
00 09 01 66 30 1d a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   
17 f0 a1 06 82 00 84 00 85 00 82 07 91 94 71 06   
00 07 19
```

I need that each time I encounter a 4b sequence to look for 09 01 sequence and replace with 03 02. This is only valid when the hexadecimal value that follows 4b is the total length of the resting sequence. In the first case, 2c represents two lines and 12 hexadecimal values(2c-> two lines and 12 hexadecimalvalues[c=12 in  hexadecimal]). In the second case, 27 represents two lines and 7 hexadecimal values.

I'm trying with something like this but I dont know how to check the hexadecimal length

```
gawk -i inplace  ' { for ( i = 1; i <= NF; ++i ) {

        if ( $i == "4b" )
            r = 1
        if ( r && $i == "09" && $(i+1) == "01" ) {
            r = 0
            $i = "03"
            $++i = "02"
        }
    }
  }
  1 ' hexadecimal.txt
```

Thanks in advance

PROBLEM 2-HEXADECIMAL ARRAY:

'm trying to find a string 1 in a txt format and each time it's found then look for an specific string 2 to change for another string 3. But, we have to watch out to the length of the resting sequence. I mean, what follows the string 1 is ALWAYS the length of the resting sequencence in hexadecimal. So, as the string 1 can appear more than once I want to check that the hexadecimal number that follows it is the length of the resting sequencence.

I need that each time I encounter a 5a sequence to look for 06 01 sequence and replace with 02 01. This is only valid when the hexadecimal value that follows 5a is the total length of the resting sequence

Imagine the next hexadecimal txt:

76 9d 6c 17 09 01 03 0e 19 0b 12 06 00 12 04 25
55 21 32 25 80 0b 12 93 00 12 04 94 71 06 00 07
19 56 62 54 48 04 00 00 00 01 6b 1e 28 1c 06 07
00 11 86 05 01 01 01 a0 11 60 0f 80 02 07 80 a1
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 5a **2c** a1 2a 02 01
b2 06 01 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14
17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 82 22 83
07 91 94 71 06 00 08 69

00 11 86 05 01 01 01 a0 11 60 0f 58 02 07 80 a1
09 06 07 04 00 23 01 22 2b 03 5a **27** a9 25 02 01
00 02 01 3e 30 1d 22 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14
17 f0 a1 06 82 00 84 00 85 00 82 07 91 94 71 06
00 07 19

09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 2b 03 5a **27** a1 25 02 01
00 06 01 66 30 1d a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14
17 f0 a1 06 22 00 22 00 85 00 82 07 91 94 71 06
00 07 19

EXPLANATION:

FIRST paragraph: 2c represents that the length of the resting sequencence that is two lines and 12 hexadecimal values(2c=two lines and 12 hexadecimalvalues[c=12 in hexadecimal])

SECOND paragraph: 27 represents that the two lines and 7 hexadecimal values.

THIRD paragraph: 27 represents that the two lines and 7 hexadecimal values.

Comment: please explain what you mean by `(length of the) resting sequence`; also, what part of the input data does the `2c` and `27` refer to (ie, what does `line` and `hexa` refer to)?

Comment: can a sequence (eg, `4b`) show up more than once in the data?

Comment: Don't use `-i inplace` while you're developing your script. Get the output you want first and then add `-i inplace` later. It doesn't need to be part of your question at all. Write your question in terms of strings in columns and rows - don't assume we know what "hexa" and "resting sequence" or any other terminology specific to your domain are or you're severely limiting the pool of people who'll be able to help you.

Comment: @markp-fuso (length of the) resting sequence refers to how many hexadecimal values are left.
2c represents the length of the sequencie. If yoy take a look after 2c you have 2 full lines with hexadecimal parameters and 12 hexadecimal values (c=12). The same happens to 27.

4b can show up more than once thats why I want to make a check with the hexadecimal value that follows 4b

Comment: I think the better way to describe the `2c` and `27` would be: *contents of the files are 2-digit hex codes; the `2c` and `27` represent the number of hex codes left in the file, ie, `2c(hex) == 44(decimal)` => 44 2-digit hex codes left in the file (after the `2c`)*

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions and additional details derived from comments and analysis:

- input data consists of a series of 2-digit hex(idecimal) codes
- a desired search pattern (eg, sequence = `4b`) only shows up once in the source data (or if it does show up more than once we're only interested in the first occurrence from a matching perspective)
- the pattern we wish to replace (eg, sequence = `09 01`) could show up more than once in the source data
- the pattern we wish to replace could be split across 2 lines (eg, sequence = `09\n01`)
- if we find **a)** a match to our search pattern (ie, `sequence = 4b`) and **b)** the next 2-digit hex code is the number of remaining 2-digit hex codes in the data set (eg, `(0x)2c` == `44(decimal)`), then **c)** make the replacement
- input and output data is limited to 16x sets of 2-digit hex codes per line

Some sample data:

```
$ cat hexa1.txt
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01   # sequence=4b, length of resting sequence = 2c(hex) = 44(decimal)
b7 09 01 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   # replace '09 01' with '03 02'
17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83
07 91 94 71 06 00 07 19                           # 44x 2-digit hex codes after '4b 2c'

$ cat hexa2.txt
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01   # sequence=4b, length of resting sequence = 2c(hex) = 44(decimal)
b7 09 01 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   # replace '09 01' with '03 02'
17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 09   # replace '09\m01' with '03\n02'
01 91 94 71 06 00 07 19                           # 44x 2-digit hex codes after '4b 2c'

$ cat hexa3.txt
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01   # sequence=4b, length of resting sequence = 2c(hex) = 44(decimal)
b7 09 01 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   # do nothing since only ...
17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83
07 91 94 71 06 00 07                              # 43x 2-digit hex codes after '4b 2c'
```

Building on OP's current `awk` solution:

```
$ cat hexa.bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

datfile="${1}"

sequence='4b'                                             # hardcoded for now; OP can parameterize this as needed

awk -v seq="${sequence}" -v outwidth=16 -v RS="" --non-decimal-data '

{ totallen=NF                                             # total number of 2-digit hex codes

  # process fields

  for ( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++ )
      { seqlen = strtonum("0x"$(i+1))                     # convert next 2-digit hex code to decimal
        if ( $i == seq && seqlen == (totallen - i - 1) )  # if current field matches our input "seq" and the next field reflects the number of 2-digit hex codes in the rest of the input data ...
           r=1                                            # then set our replacement flag to 1
        if ( r && $i == "09" && $(i+1) == "01" )          # if the replacement flag == 1 ...
                                                          # and the current/next fields are "09" and "01", respectively ...
           { $i="03"                                      # then replace the current/next
             $++i="02"                                    # fields with "03" and "02"
           }
      }

  # print fields to stdout, use "outwidth" to determine
  # max number of fields to place on a line of output

  pfx=""
  for ( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++ )
      { printf "%s%s", pfx, $i
        pfx=" "
        if ( i % outwidth == 0 )                         # for every outwidth (16th) field add a newline character
           { printf "\n"
             pfx=""
           }
      }
  if ( pfx == " " )
     printf "\n"                                         # append newline character to last line of output
}
' "${datfile}" > "${datfile}.new"

echo "++++++++++++++++++ differences between input (${datfile}) and output (${datfile}.new):"

sdiff "${datfile}" "${datfile}.new"
```

Where:

- `-v seq="${sequence}"` - pass search sequence in as awk variable "seq"
- `-v outwidth=16` - output to be limited to 16x 2-digit hex codes per line
- `-v RS=""` - clear the row separator, ie, treat input data as one long single line; this will allow us to find our match if it spans 2 lines (ie, convert `09\n01` to `09 01`)
- **NOTE**: the search and replace patterns (`09 01` and `03 02`, repsectively) are hardcoded for this particular exercise; OP could parameterize these as needed
- **UDPATE**: borrowed @restricteur's `strtonum()` to convert a 2-digit hex code to decimal

Running the above against our sample data sets:

```
# one pair of "09 01" replaced:

$ hexa.bash  hexa1.txt
++++++++++++++++++ differences between input (hexa1.txt) and output (hexa1.txt.new):
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01                 09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01
b7 09 01 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14               | b7 03 02 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14
17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83                 17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83
07 91 94 71 06 00 07 19                                         07 91 94 71 06 00 07 19

# two pairs of "09 01" replaced:

$ hexa.bash  hexa2.txt
++++++++++++++++++ differences between input (hexa2.txt) and output (hexa2.txt.new):
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01                 09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01
b7 09 01 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14               | b7 03 02 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14
17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 09               | 17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 03
01 91 94 71 06 00 07 19                                       | 02 91 94 71 06 00 07 19

# no replacements:

$ hexa.bash  hexa3.txt
++++++++++++++++++ differences between input (hexa3.txt) and output (hexa3.txt.new):
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01                 09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01
b7 09 01 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14                 b7 09 01 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14
17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83                 17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83
07 91 94 71 06 00 07                                            07 91 94 71 06 00 07
```

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso. Sorry to disturb you again but the solution got the hexadecimal unordered dometimes. Could you take a look yo the problem 2? (I post above the other question)

Thanks for your patience, I am a begginer in this

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `hexadecimal unordered`; I can see one issue will be your original question was based on a single string of codes per file, while you've now added, basically, a whole new question based on multiple sets of codes in a single file; the issue is that my answer (above) was geared specifically towards your first question (ie, one set of codes per file) and will not work for your new question (multiple sets of codes per file)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
    gawk ' NR==FNR { totalRecords += NF; lines = NR; next }
    {
    for ( i = 1; i <= NF; ++i ) {
        
        if ( $i == "4b" )
        {
            expected = strtonum( "0x"$(i+1) );
            rest = totalRecords-16*(NR-lines-1)-i-1
            if(expected == rest) {
                r = 1
            }
            
        }
        if (r && $i == "09" && $(i+1) == "01" ) {
            r = 0
            $i = "03"
            $++i = "02"
        }
    }
    }
    1 ' hexadecimal.txt hexadecimal.txt
```

The code starts by computing the total number of records in the file and the total number of its lines in the first pass.

Then, in the second pass when it encounters "0b" it computes finds the expected number of records $(i+1) and computes the actual number of remaining records (rest)  based on the total number of records in the file, the number of lines in the file and the number of the current line.

Thus when "09 01" is encountered the program checks the condition that the expected number of records is equal to the actual number of remaining records as well.

Comment: It looks nice but doesnt work. Im trying to figure out what happen

Comment: Could you explain please

Comment: It works fine for me. I edited my answer with some explanations. I also modified the code a little bit so that the condition (expected == rest) is stored in r when "4b" is encountered. I also removed -i inplace so that you can see the result of the command without altering the file. Maybe you are using a modified file instead of the original one.  You can add -i inplace back when you check that everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

> 4b can show up more than once thats why I want to make a check with the hexadecimal value that follows 4b.

Then would you please try the following:

```
awk 'function replace(j, len) {                         # this function modifies global variable a and i
        len = strtonum("0x" a[i+1])                     # calculate the length of the resting sequence
        i += 2                                          # increment the index by two for "4b" and the length
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {                     # iterate among the sequence
            if (a[i] == "09" && a[i+1] == "01") {       # if the replacees are found
                a[i++] = "03"; a[i] = "02"; j++         # then replace them and increment j to avoid overlap
            }
            i++                                         # increment the global index
        }
    }
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) a[++n] = $i           # read the entire strings in the array a
    }
    END {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {                      # search for the bytes in turn
            if (a[i] == "4b") replace()                 # if "4b" is found, call the function
        }                                               # note that the index "i" is incremented in the function
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {                      # format and output the array
            printf(a[i] (i%16? " " : "\n"))             # put a whitespace or newline depending on the column position
        }
        if (n%16) printf("\n")                          # if the column ends before 16th, add a newline
    }
' example.txt
```

As an example which contains multiple `4b`s, I have merged the provided two examples as follows:

```
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01   
b7 09 01 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   
17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83   
07 91 94 71 06 00 07 19 2b 03 4b 27 a1 25 02 01   
00 09 01 66 30 1d a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   
17 f0 a1 06 82 00 84 00 85 00 82 07 91 94 71 06   
00 07 19
```

Output for the input file above:

```
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01
b7 03 02 47 30 22 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14
17 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83
07 91 94 71 06 00 07 19 2b 03 4b 27 a1 25 02 01
00 03 02 66 30 1d a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14
17 f0 a1 06 82 00 84 00 85 00 82 07 91 94 71 06
00 07 19
```

You'll see the `09 01` sequences are replaced with `03 02` in two positions.